# Number of subsets that contain an arithmetic progression.

Tags: combinatorics

There is a set $X=\{1,2,3,...,n\}$

Let $$F=\{A\subset X:\{a,a+b,...,a+(k-1)b\}\subset A, \ a,b\in X \}$$ $F$ is a family of all subsets of $X$ such all of them contains at least one arithmetic progression. $k$ is fixed.

> Calculate $|F|$

Generally let $\mu:2^{X}\to \mathbb{R}$ be some measure.

> Calculate $\sum_{A\in F}\mu(A)$

Thank you

EDIT:

Let describe this situation more precisely: Let
$$f:X\to \mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}$$ be any function.
Then our measure can be written as
$$\mu(A)=\sum_{l\in A}f(l)$$
Then $$\sum_{A\in F}\mu(A)=\sum_{l=1}^{n}a(l,n,k)\cdot f(l)$$
Where $a(l,n,k)$ is a number of subsets of $X$ that contain $l$ and contain some arithmetic progression that its length is at least $k$

Comment: What is exactly your doubt? What did try?

Comment: If $a$ and $b$ are also fixed (and valid), then the number of such sets is $2^{n-k}$ (or their combined measure is $2^{n-k}\frac{\mu(X)+\mu(\{a,a+b,\ldots,a+(k-1)b\})}2$

Comment: $a,b$ are not fixed

Comment: @mkultra Yes, but that is a first stepping-stone. Perhaps inclusion-exclusion principle can help after that?